# How to install apxs module on apache 2.4.6

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, apache2

I have just used `apt-get update` and my apache has been updated to `2.4.6`.

i want to install apxs for compiling modules and i get this error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2-prefork-dev : Depends: apache2.2-common (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can i fix that

Answer (score 59):

to install apxs on ubuntu, install the`apache2-dev` package.

```
sudo apt install apache2-dev
```

Comment: `sudo apt install apache2-dev` for newer versions

Answer (score 13):

To install `apxs` on Oracle Linux run:

`yum install httpd-devel`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot install httpd-devel on cpanel. You will need to install ea-apache24-devel

https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/install-httpd-devel.594631/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, when setting up Apache2 + PHP, apxs is actually not needed anymore.
You should install libapache2-mod-php instead.
`sudo apt install apache2`
`sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php`

Answer (score -3):

APC is currently not compatible with the version. Try adding native opcode cache in it.

Comment: APXS is not APC. They aren't even related. (APXS is a tool used to build and install Apache modules, and APC is a PHP extension.)