# Issue while compiling apache2 with mod_perl

Tags: perl, compiler-errors, apache2, mod-perl2

```
perl Makefile.PL MP_USE_STATIC=1 \
MP_AP_PREFIX=/tmp/https2.2.34 \
MP_AP_CONFIGURE=“—with-mpm=prefork \
—prefix=/tmp/apache-2.2.34 \
-enable-modules=‘ssl rewrite info alias auth_basic usertrack so’”
```

ERROR from evaluation of /tmp/mod_perl-2.0.10/Apache-Reload/Makefile.PL: Use of uninitialized value in substitution (s///) at Apache-Test/lib/TestRun.pm line 1100.

```
Os: sun Os 5.10 sun4v sparc SUNW,T5240
cc - /bin/cc
make - /usr/CORE/bin/make - GNU make 3.80
Perl - /bin/perl - v5.8.4
Apache - 2.2.34
Mod_perl - 2.0.10
```

Comment: Did you really enter that command with curly quotes?

Comment: Yes. I entered with quotes

Comment: No, I specifically mean _curly_ quotes -- `“` and `”` instead of `"`, for instance.

Comment: Sorry i dont know what a curly quote means. I used double quotes. Stack overflow changes the font which is why it may look so.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the eval fails because of fatal warnings from the undef value.

Can you try this patch in **Apache-Test** at **loc 1100** and report back the output?

**Index: lib/Apache/TestRun.pm**

```
my %args = @Apache::TestMM::Argv;
while (my($k, $v) = each %args) {
  unless (defined $v) {
      die "key $k has no value";
  }
  $v =~ s/\|/\\|/g;
  $body .= "\n\$Apache::TestConfig::Argv{'$k'} = q|$v|;\n";
}
```

If it shows `key apxs has no value`, then it means either apxs module is not installed or script is not able to find the path where apxs module is installed.

To check if `apxs module` is installed or not, run following command

`which apxs` --> shows path where it is installed

If above command doesn't show anything, it means it is not installed, so you can installed it by running following command

`sudo apt-get install apache2-dev`

Now run `which apxs` command again and check where it is installed, most probably it will show `/usr/bin/apxs`

Now run `Makefile.PL` with addition of following line

`MP_APXS=/usr/bin/apxs`

So command should be like this

```
perl Makefile.PL MP_APXS=/usr/bin/apxs
```

Now it should go properly without any interruption.

Comment: Error: Key apxs has no value

Comment: I think `apxs` is not installed in your system. Do you have `apxs module` installed, if not [follow this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18566774/how-to-install-apxs-module-on-apache-2-4-6)

Comment: I dont have apxs installed. Apxs is apache xtension if am not wrong. I am trying to compile apache with static mod_perl. So xs should be compiled along with apache right

Comment: it is a separate package and comes under apache development package.

Comment: MP_APXS and MP_AP_PREFIX are mutually exclusive

Comment: No it's not. `MP_AP_PREFIX` must point to an extracted Apache 2.0 source tree, while `MP_APXS` must point to the `apxs` binaries.

Comment: [ Error ] You need to pass either MP_AP_PREFIX or MP_APXS but not both  @Prashant. I get this error if I use both.

Comment: Sorry my bad! . So I think apxs is not included with apache httpd source code.

Comment: instead of `static installation` did you try with `dynamic`

Comment: Yes, I switched to dynamic compile and completed my installation. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: I don't think we have a straight forward answer  to the static installation. Hence I've accepted your comment on dynamic installation method and upvote it.